# Is mysql escape string enough while using post method with android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-injection

I have an android app and it is connected to a php page with post method 
And I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string, as user can't see any error while logging in to my app in android,

Is escape string enough to prevent sql injection in my case ?

> Am Using volley in android to post data

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
```

Comment: Probably. Can you show the code where you build the query?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the variable is inside a string or not, if it is then you're fairly safe but there should be no reason just to implement prepared statements instead. Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Example below is from that site.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```